# Soundtrack of Three Colors White

Tags: history

I am trying to find the soundtracks of the movie "Three colors White",can any one tell that who composed music?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The soundtrack was by [Zbigniew Preisner](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0006237/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr4), who wrote the soundtrack to all three "Three colours:" movies, Blue, White & Red.

More info & listenable excerpts on [AllMusic : Trois Couleurs: Blanc](http://www.allmusic.com/album/trois-couleurs-blanc-original-film-soundtrack-mw0000115196)